# Reuse parameters in psycopg2.execute

Tags: python, parameters, psycopg2

I have SQL query like this (I know this case could be optimized, my point is using different queries with same parameters):

```
select * from a where x > %s and y < %s
union
select * from b where x > %s and y < %s
union
select * from c where x > %s and y < %s
union
select * from d where x > %s and y < %s
```

and I use psycopg2 execute to fill the parameters:

```
mycursor.execute(query_from_above, (since, to, since, to, since, to, since, to))
```

And I would like to call it like this

```
mycursor.execute(query_from_above, (since, to))
```

Is it possible to modify the query somehow so I can use the shorter version of execute()?

EDIT:
There are solutions for this problem: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries
and probably a better one: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mycursor.execute("""select * from a where x > %(since)s and y < %(to)s
                    union
                    select * from b where x > %(since)s and y < %(to)s
                    union
                    select * from c where x > %(since)s and y < %(to)s
                    union
                    select * from d where x > %(since)s and y < %(to)s""",
                  {'since': since, 'to': to}
                 )
```

Could try something like this?